# Using Java 8 parallelStream inside Spark mapParitions

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, java-8, spark-streaming

I am trying to understand the behavior of Java 8 parallel stream inside spark parallelism. When I run the below code, I am expecting the output size of `listOfThings` to be the same as input size. But that's not the case, I sometimes have missing items in my output. This behavior is not consistent. If I just iterate through the iterator instead of using `parallelStream`, everything is fine. Count matches every time.

```
// listRDD.count = 10
JavaRDD test = listRDD.mapPartitions(iterator -> {
    List listOfThings = IteratorUtils.toList(iterator);
    return listOfThings.parallelStream.map(
        //some stuff here
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
});
// test.count = 9
// test.count = 10
// test.count = 8
// test.count = 7
```

Comment: the person that down voted the post. Can you please let me know why?

Comment: Although I agree that re-parallelize work inside Spark doesn't seem like a good idea I don't think Akash's answer is the correct one. I think we need more details to answer the question. One obvious think would be to log size of `listOfThings` or just add it to the output as a part of `map`.  I suspect that things might get broken at this stage already.

Answer (score 0):

1. it's a very good question.
2. Whats going on here is `Race Condition`. when you parallelize the stream then stream split the full list into several equal parts [Based on avaliable threads and size of list] then it tries to run subparts independently on each avaliable thread to perform the work.

But you are also using apache spark which is famous for computing the work faster i.e. general purpose computation engine. Spark uses the same approach [parallelize the work] to perform the action.

Now Here in this Scenerio what is happening is Spark already parallelized the whole work then inside this you are again parallelizing the work due to this the race condition starts i.e. spark executor starts processing the work and then you parallelized the work then stream process aquires other thread and start processing IF THE THREAD THAT WAS PROCESSING STREAM WORK FINISHES WORK BEFORE THE SPARK EXECUTOR COMPLETE HIS WORK THEN IT ADD THE RESULT OTHERWISE SPARK EXECUTOR CONTINUES TO REPORT RESULT TO MASTER.

3. This is not a good approach to re-parallelize the work it will always gives you the pain let the spark do it for you.

Hope you understand whats going on here

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate more? AFAIK, Spark launches individual executors and all the tasks run in that JVM. So how can spark executor finishes when there are still threads running inside parallel stream in that JVM?

Comment: @Falan Since the parallel stream runs on a different executor hence the spark;s thread will not control over the parallel stream threads. For spark thread to wait until parallel stream finishes it's work, you have use Thread Joins.

Comment: @Falan hope you understand now whats going on

Comment: I tried parallel stream in spark map.. It is working fine in my local and my spark cluster.. How can I reproduce this issue?