# How to perform multi threading or parallel processing in spark implemented in scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

Hi am having a spark streaming program which is reading the events from eventhub and pushing it topics. for processing each batch it is taking almost 10 times the batch time.

when am trying to implement multithreading am not able to see much difference in the processing time.

Is there any way by which I can increase the performance either by doing parallel processing. or start some 1000 threads at a time and just keep pushing the messages.

```
class ThreadExample(msg:String) extends Thread{  
        override def run {
         var test = new PushToTopicDriver(msg)
          test.push()
          // println(msg)
        }
}  
object HiveEventsDirectStream {

def b2s(a: Array[Byte]): String = new String(a)

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val eventhubnamespace = "namespace"
val progressdir = "/Event/DirectStream/"
val eventhubname_d = "namespacestream"
val ehParams = Map[String, String](
  "eventhubs.policyname" -> "PolicyKeyName",
  "eventhubs.policykey" -> "key",
  "eventhubs.namespace" -> "namespace",
  "eventhubs.name" -> "namespacestream",
  "eventhubs.partition.count" -> "30",
  "eventhubs.consumergroup" -> "$default",
  "eventhubs.checkpoint.dir" -> "/EventCheckpoint_0.1",
  "eventhubs.checkpoint.interval" -> "2"
)
println("testing spark")
val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("Eventhubs_Test")
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[PublishToTopic]))
conf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
val sc= new SparkContext(conf)
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val pool:ExecutorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
var dataString :RDD[String] =sc.emptyRDD
val stream=EventHubsUtils.createDirectStreams(ssc,eventhubnamespace,progressdir,Map(eventhubname_d -> ehParams))
val kv1 = stream.map(receivedRecord => (new String(receivedRecord.getBody))).persist()
kv1.foreachRDD(rdd_1 => rdd_1.foreachPartition(line => line.foreach(msg => {var t1 = new ThreadExample(msg) t1.start()})))
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()

}
```

}

Thanks,

Ankush Reddy.

Comment: Spark already does parallel processing.  Generally you don't want to spawn your own threads and instead handle the parallelism though spark.  You can try increasing the number of partitions, but adding parallelism isn't guaranteed to help, it depends on your data and the transformations you are trying to do.

Comment: @puhlen when I try to increase the partition with repartition this is consuming some time. I am working on real time data so need to consume data at a very good pace.

Comment: I am actually surprised you're able to do this. Are you losing any data at all? I had a similar question but was not able to find a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665304/using-java-8-parallelstream-inside-spark-mapparitions

Comment: @Falan No exactly but every job is waiting until the last task gets executed. which is again getting delayed in the starting up the next batch. Still exploring solutions.

Comment: You definitely do _not_ want to start spinning up your own threads. What you probably need are either more executors (how many do you have now?) or maybe more shards and readers (how many do you have now?).